# Pointer arithmetic; Must do it twice initally

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I have a piece of code here that I'm a bit confused about. It seems that if I use: `p = &j`, it takes two increments just to begin traversing `a[]`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int a[4] = {5,2,6,4};
  int j = a[0];
  int *p;

  p = &j;

  printf("*p = %d\n", *p);
  printf("a[0] = %d\n", a[0]);
  printf("address of a[0] = %p\n", &a[0]);

  printf("\np++\n\n");
  p++;

  printf("*p = %d\n", *p);
  printf("a[1] = %d\n", a[1]);
  printf("address of a[1] = %p\n", &a[1]);

  printf("\np++\n\n");
  p++;

  printf("*p = %d\n", *p);
  printf("a[2] = %d\n", a[2]);
  printf("address of a[2] = %p\n", &a[2]);

  return 0;
}
```

If I use `p = &a[0]`, then it works fine. Why is it when I use `&j`, it takes two `p++`'s to start. You can see `*p = 5` twice before it starts incrementing through the array. Why is this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Putting `p = &j;` doesn't point to the beginning of array `a`. Issue likely stems from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a really cool bug to run into, especially for someone who is just beginning to learn C.  Understanding this seemingly strange behaviour will improve your understanding of how your programs work quite a bit.

Your code does not work properly because `int j` and `a[0]` do not have the same address, that is to say, `&j != &a[0]`.

Let me use a graphic to explain why.

All of your local variables `a[], j, p, etc...` are allocated on your program's [**call stack**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#Structure).

So, in your example, the stack may *hypothetically* look like this:

[image]

You can see from this *wonderfully artistic* diagram that the address of `a` is `0x1004` whereas address of `j` evaluates to `0x1000`.

Just because 2 variables have the same value does not imply that they will have the same memory address.  That is what's happening here.  You give j the **value** of a[0], but they are still 2 seperate, unrelated pieces of memory.

The mysterious behaviour of why incrementing the pointer puts you at the start of `a[]` can be explained by the fact that both `j` and `a[]` are allocated on the **stack**.  j's address will probably be right below `a[]`'s address.  Indeed, as you can see in my magnum opus of art, if we were to move upwards 4 bytes from `&j`, we would arrive at `&a[]`.

---

Edit 1 as per Eugene Sh.:

PLEASE NOTE: incrementing a pointer like this is undefined behaviour in a C program.  The ordering of variables on the stack is undefined and depends on the compiler, you may get a different result every time your code recompiles.  Please please never never ever ever do this in a real program.  Doing p++ will result in undefined behaviour.

Edit 2:

You could carry out a cool experiment by printing out the addresses of all your variables.

```
int main()
{
    int a[4] = {5, 2, 6, 4};
    int j = a[0];
    int* p;

    //in printf, %p stands for "print pointer"
    printf("&a[0] = %p\n", &a[0]);
    printf("&j    = %p\n", &j);
    printf("&p    = %p\n", &p);     //the address of a pointer.... craaazy
    printf("p     = %p\n", p);      //should print same address as &j

    //..............................
}
```

Comment: @unixpipe do you understand my explaination?  If there is **any** lack of clarity, let me know and I will fix it :).

Comment: Hi . yes i do understand it and it is very well explained. i did know that j and a[0] did have different addresses but i guess I had it in my head that I can just point to j since it had the first element of the array and it would increment. It does increment but it takes two p++'s to do so. the last paragraph hit home. j is located right below the array. which is why it takes two p++'s. Thanks so much!

Comment: I do understand that is undefined behavior. j's address could be located somewhere else next time or on another machine or compiler so incrementing it twice wouldn't have the same effect since it might be somewhere completely different. maybe even above a[] correct? Is this what you are mentioning?

Comment: @unixpipe Yes, exactly. But the problem, that it is not only you who is reading the answer.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thank you for *pointing* (ha) this misinformation out!  Please check my edit and see if it is clear enough :)  `stack_overflow_error* eugenesh;`

Answer (score 1):

You are encountering an undefined behaviour here. By taking the address of `j` into `p` you are getting the address of `j` only, and by no means of the beginning of `a`. The line `int j = a[0];` is assigning the *value* of the first `a`s element to the `j`, but not its address. And by incrementing `p` you are going out of bounds of the defined memory space and thus invoking UB.

Answer (score 1):

You must remember how to make pointers point to a part of an array. What you are doing is assigning the value to the address of an integer (which points to element 0 of said array ... trouble).

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{

  int a[4] = {5,2,6,4};

  /* Always initialize your variables */
  int *p = NULL;
  int i = 0;

  p = a;

      for (i=0; i < 4; i++)
      {
        printf("Number is = %d,\n", p[i]); // or p + i * sizeof(int)

      }

  return 0;
  }




---Results are----

./a.out 
Number is = 5,
Number is = 2,
Number is = 6,
Number is = 4,
```

Comment: Tlancenka added a good point that Pointer arithmetic should be done carefully

Answer (score 0):

```
 int j = a[0]
```

does not make j an alias for the first element of the array a, it defines a new int variable j, which is initialised to a copy of the first element of a.
Therefore

```
 p = &j;
```

p is not pointing at any element of a, but at the separate variable j.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot add comments, this is the only way I can react to previous answers, which I myself influenced.

Xofo: Actually, I am sorry, I confused you as much as I confused myself.
It of course could be p[i] like I pointed out, but the second edit (in the commentary) is wrong. p[i] = *(p + i), therefore your version was right as well. If it was to contain sizeof(int), it would have to be something like *(p + [sizeof(int) * i]), which I am not sure if that is even possible in C.